Why the contribution of a categorical value in SHAP trained on Catboost differs from observation to observation
Context
Let's imagine I am interested in predicting sepal length in the iris dataset using catboost.
Objective
My main objective is understanding the effect of each categorical value for target in the fitting. For that I will be using SHAP to understand contributions on the prediction.
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

# Load Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
data = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
data['target'] = iris.target

# Set the target to sepal length
X = data.drop(columns=['sepal length (cm)'])
y = data['sepal length (cm)']

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


# Initialize and train the CatBoostClassifier
# Initialize and train the CatBoostRegressor
cat_features = ['target']
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=100, learning_rate=0.1, depth=6, verbose=False)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, cat_features=cat_features)


Now I use shap
import shap
shap.initjs()

# Calculate SHAP values
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

# Visualize SHAP values
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X, feature_names=X.columns)

But I am only interested in knowing the associated effect of a specific value in the target variable (for example value 0 that is associated to setosa).
For that I just filter the dataset where the observations are 0 in target.
# Filter the dataset for target = 0
X_test_target_0 = X_test[X_test['target'] == 0]

# Get the corresponding SHAP values
shap_values_target_0 = explainer.shap_values(X_test_target_0)

# Display SHAP values for target = 0 observation 0
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_target_0, X_test_target_0, feature_names=X.columns)
shap_values_instance = shap_values_target_0[1]

# Display SHAP values for target = 0 observation 1
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values_instance, X_test_target_0.iloc[1], feature_names=X.columns,matplotlib=True)


Question to solve
However when I check the values associated to it they are very different and I assumed they would be equal.
print(X.columns)
target_index = list(X.columns).index('target')
shap_values_target_0


Why are they different?, my assumption was they should be the same.
Thank you for the answer in advanced ! :)

Originally posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78759354/10495893

There is a difference because the effect of the species ("target") is not independent of the other features: the GBM you have built has nontrivial (and perhaps even very complex) feature interactions.  SHAP attributes those interaction effects to the underlying raw features, and that leads to different SHAP values for a feature across different observations even when that feature takes the same value.  This isn't just limited to categorical features (or to CatBoost): you can probably observe the same thing when you keep one of your numerical features constant and vary the other features, obtaining different SHAP values for that one numerical feature.

So then the only way to give an average attribution is to calculate the average or the median of those effects in general terms ? That is mean(shap_values_target_0[taget_index])?

Yes, that's what I would look at. Or even better, a plot of the distribution of shap values.
